# Make Swagger output the description of an IRouteConstraint

Tags: asp.net-core, swagger, asp.net-core-webapi, swashbuckle

I have a route with a custom IRouteConstraint.
Swagger generates the parameter section but the description field is always empty. For other parameters I get the description from the XML comments correctly.
The only workaround I found so far is adding a Operation filter and set the description there for the

```
 foreach ( var parameter in operation.Parameters.OfType<NonBodyParameter>() )
        {
            if (parameter.Name == RouteConstraint.Name)
            {
                parameter.Description = GetConstraintDescription();
            }
```

Any way to instruct swagger to get the description from the XML comments for IRouteConstraints.

Comment: Can you show us a bit more code? Or maybe a create a minimal project on GitHub and post a link to it?

Comment: I made a very simple sample: https://github.com/apopovsky/swagger-web-test
If you browse to /swagger/v1/swagger.json you'll see the id parameter has a description (from xml docs) but the "sector" constraint doesn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My current solution is this class, based on the Swashbuckle XmlCommentsOperationFilter.

```
public class RouteConstraintXmlDocsOperationFilter:IOperationFilter
{
    private readonly XPathNavigator _xmlNavigator;
    private const string MemberXPath = "/doc/members/member[@name='{0}']";
    private const string SummaryXPath = "summary";


    public RouteConstraintXmlDocsOperationFilter(string filePath)
    {
        XPathDocument xmlDoc = new XPathDocument(filePath);
        _xmlNavigator = xmlDoc.CreateNavigator();
    }


    public void Apply(Operation operation, OperationFilterContext context)
    {
        ApplyConstraintsXmlToActionParameters(operation.Parameters, context.ApiDescription);
    }

    private void ApplyConstraintsXmlToActionParameters(IList<IParameter> parameters, ApiDescription apiDescription)
    {
        var nonBodyParameters = parameters.OfType<NonBodyParameter>();
        foreach (var parameter in nonBodyParameters)
        {                // Check for a corresponding action parameter?
            var actionParameter = apiDescription.ParameterDescriptions.FirstOrDefault(p =>
                parameter.Name.Equals(p.Name, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
            if (actionParameter == null) continue;

            if (!actionParameter.RouteInfo.Constraints.Any()) continue;

            var constraintType = actionParameter.RouteInfo.Constraints.FirstOrDefault().GetType();
            var commentIdForType = XmlCommentsIdHelper.GetCommentIdForType(constraintType);
            var constraintSummaryNode = _xmlNavigator
                .SelectSingleNode(string.Format(MemberXPath, commentIdForType))
                ?.SelectSingleNode(SummaryXPath);
            if (constraintSummaryNode != null)
            {
                parameter.Description = XmlCommentsTextHelper.Humanize(constraintSummaryNode.InnerXml);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

To set it up:

```
services.AddSwaggerGen(o =>
        {
            var fileName = GetType().GetTypeInfo().Module.Name.Replace(".dll", ".xml").Replace(".exe", ".xml");
            o.IncludeXmlComments(Path.Combine(AppContext.BaseDirectory, fileName));
            o.SwaggerDoc("v1", new Info { Title = "My API", Version = "v1" });
            o.OperationFilter<RouteConstraintXmlDocsOperationFilter>(Path.Combine(AppContext.BaseDirectory, fileName));
        })
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid that the only "easy way" is what you already implemented (an Operation filter)

I was looking at the XML description that your project outputs

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<doc>
    <assembly>
        <name>SwaggerWeb</name>
    </assembly>
    <members>
        <member name="M:SwaggerWeb.Controllers.ValuesController.Get(System.Int32)">
            <summary> Get by ID </summary>
            <param name="id">The value ID</param>
            <returns></returns>
        </member>
        <member name="T:SwaggerWeb.SectorRouteConstraint">
            <summary> Sector constraint </summary>
        </member>
    </members>
</doc>
```

You can try make your filter a bit more generic and fish the description out of the XML, but other than that I do not see any other way.

Comment: I think the same but I'm new to Swager and Swashbuckle so maybe someone knew another way. Thanks!

Comment: @ArielPopovsky In theory there is a way! Swashbuckle is OpenSource in a perfect world the correction should be made there, but I see this as a very edge case, not sure this will bring a lot to the community